# Unable to delete old calendars from Microsoft Outlook Android App

Tags: calendar, delete, outlook

Software:

- Microsoft Outlook App on Android
- Microsoft Outlook for Windows, version 2007

I currently have a work account which I have synced with my Android, and for some reason, all of the calendars I've ever accepted on my work's account (and deleted on my desktop) are still showing up on my Outlook App on my Android.

Aside from being annoying (given that all their respective reminders are still popping up), I have on many occasions accidentally added a new reminder onto an old calendar which, if isn't a "shown" calendar, ends up hidden and I never know about it.

How to delete old calendars from Microsoft Outlook Android App?

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (the question was migrated and OP didn't join the site, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I found [the discussion on Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/osettings-ocalset/deleted-calendar-showing-up-in-ios-outlook-app/2812d42a-4bdd-464c-9077-b1517d6f665c) helpful:

What worked in my case was:

1. Deleting both Outlook account from account settings *and* Outlook app
2. Creating a Microsoft Exchange account according to instructions from the link above
3. Installing once again Outlook app, but this time using not Outlook settings but Microsoft Exchange settings